# Creating a DNS with BIND : no servers could be reached

Tags: centos, debian, bind, redhat

I would like to set up a DNS server with Bind on CentOS 7. I followed a tutorial, on my server everything seems to work.

[Test on CentOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpYds.png)

However when I try to use my DNS server with a client, it doesn't work. My server has IP 192.168.10.250 and my client : 192.168.10.13 Here are the tests I did :

[Test on Debian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkR9o.png)

Here is the configuration of my DNS :

[Config named](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJgGb.png)

[Config db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GhBx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly configured your SELinux contexts for BIND and ensured that your firewall is properly configured to allow DNS traffic to and from clients?

Here is an [SELinux policy](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-bind_selinux/) for BIND you can use.

You can determine whether or not your SELinux configuration is correct in one of two days.

1. You can run `setenforce 0` to temporarily set SELinux to Permissive mode where it will not block unauthorized access.
2. You can evaluate the contents of `/var/log/audit.log` while running BIND to see if the process generates any log messages indicating that you have improperly configured SELinux contexts.

As for your firewall, you need to ensure that iptables, firewalld, etc is allowing UDP Traffic on port 53 in and out of your DNS Server.

Lastly, an additional troubleshooting step request. What occurs when you perform a DNS Lookup against the DNS Server from the DNS Server itself? EG:

`dig google.com @127.0.0.1`. Does this succeed? This will help indicate whether or not your firewall is configured properly.